# Spark write table into parquet format without concatenating into one file

Tags: apache-spark

```
insert overwrite 
  directory '/HDS_VOL_TMP/ic/test_folder'
  stored as parquet 
select 
  a
from test_table
where part_key = 20200501
```

I have to export data for users. I want to export it in parquet format such that the size can be reduced.
However spark always reduce into one file which greatly increase the execution time.

Does anyone know how to switch off the final reduce task and allowing it to export multi files?

Thanks

Comment: add  code snippet.. `repartiiton` can help.. check if `coalesce(1)` is being used in code

Comment: Will repartition add extra tasks and increase the execution time?

Comment: Does Spark split the inputs into multiple partitions, then concatenate them into just 1 partition (hence just 1 file if the size is not too big), or does Spark simply use 1 partition from the start??? Check the HistoryServer if you have it running.

Answer (score 0):

Use `bucketBy(numBuckets: Int, colName: String, colNames: String*)` api to split the file into number of files.

According to doc-

```
 /**
   * Buckets the output by the given columns. If specified, the output is laid out on the file
   * system similar to Hive's bucketing scheme.
   *
   * This is applicable for all file-based data sources (e.g. Parquet, JSON) starting with Spark
   * 2.1.0.
   *
   * @since 2.0
   */
```